# Xcode 5 : AdHoc iTunesAdwork

Tags: xcode, itunesartwork

I've an AdHoc distribution for my iOS application.
However, I find it very ugly that the application has no icon in iTunes.

I've added the iTunesArtwork without extension to the root of the project, but it won't appear in iTunes.

What can I do now?

I'm running the latest version of XCode.

I've searched online, it says to put the file in the resources folder - but my application does not contain any folder named resources.